# How to use countries gem to generate a list of country names as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a rails api and need to send all country as `JSON` using `AMS`. I am able to fetch the countries but not able to send it as `JSON`.
I get the error: `undefined method [] for nil class`

```
def index
  countries = Country.all
  render json: countries, serializer: CountrySerializer
end
```

```
class CountrySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer 
  attributes(:name)
end
```

I am expecting the `JSON` response to be an array like

```
[
 England,
 Netherland
]
```

I was hoping I could make use of serializers so I could translate the names in different languages

Comment: Please post the code for your `CountrySerializer`

Comment: added the serializer but it never reaches till the serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, serializers are configured to work with Rails models, and your data is coming from the `countries` gem.

If all you need is the name attribute you can do:

```
def index
  countries = Country.all
  render json: { countries: ISO3166::Country.all.map(&:name) }
end
```

Comment: `def index
        countries = Country.all.map(&:name)
        render json: countries.to_json
 end`  I have done as you suggested but setting a serializer didn't work. I got an error like undefined method model name. Are serializers specific to a model because I dont have a country table in my database

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer with a solution that might work for you. Can you edit your question to show an example of the output that you were trying to get from the serializer?

Comment: I have updated my question with the output. And thank you for help

Comment: No problem. Ah, I see; I think I know what you're looking for. I've updated the answer.